# Is there a penalty for rolling a 401(k) into new employer while the markets are down?

Tags: 401k, retirement-plan, rollover

I have a 401(k) account with my old employer which I have not rolled over yet to my new employer. As I am no longer contributing to the old account or employed by them, I am wondering if there any penalties to leaving that account open. Is it common to be charged a fee to keep a 401(k) open after leaving a company?

I am also looking at the performance of the account. According to the dashboard, that account is down nearly 20% over a period of 1 year. If I roll it over to my new 401(k), I believe that means any investments it is kept in (it's 100% invested in growth & income) will be sold locking in the market value, and then it is moved to my new account where it can be re-invested. Is my understanding correct?

And if so, is it bad to roll it over while the markets are down this much? Or will it not matter in the end as it should grow similarly in either account?

I am concerned that I will take a greater penalty rolling it over with the current market if there is no cost or other penalty with keeping it with my former employer for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - only cash can be rolled over between plans. Realizing gains or losses within a 401(k) or IRA has no tax consequence because you only pay tax when you withdraw funds. Even then, you pay tax on the entire withdrawal, not just the gains, so there's no "cost basis" to keep track of for tax purposes.

> is it bad to roll it over while the markets are down this much?

No - you may be "selling low", but you're *buying* low as well. So the growth would be the same either way (assuming you buy relatively similar investments).

The opposite would be true as well - if the market were up, you'd be selling high, but would be buying high as well. So there's no reason based on the current market why you should or should not roll over your 401(k).

The reason to roll over would be:

- Avoiding extra fees for leaving funds on a company's 401(K) that you no longer work at
- More flexibility in what you can invest in if you roll to an IRA
- Consolidation of assets if you roll to a new employer's 401(k).

The last two are a trade-off - more control vs simpler setup. If you are fine just investing in your employer's 401(k) assets and would prefer keeping everything in one basket there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: One small wrinkle. When companies do a rollover, sometimes there is a blackout/transfer period where you are holding cash. If the market rose during that blackout period you might miss out on some gains. You still aren't losing any value, but there is a potential for opportunity cost being out of the market.